# Keychain how to delete specific item only

Tags: ios, iphone, keychain

I am new to iOS. I needed to save data locally. As in android we can save data in sharedPreferences. and developer can clear whole shared preferences and can delete/remove specific key also.

I am using keychain for that purpose. But now I want to delete/remove only one key. but I am having problem on how to do that. here is my code of keychain that I got from SO.

```
    public class KeychainService: NSObject {

    static let USER_PIN : String = "USER_PIN"
    static let LOGGEDIN_ID : String = "LOGGEDIN_ID"
    static let USER_NAME : String = "USER_NAME"
    static let IS_USER_LOGGEDIN : String = "IS_USER_LOGGEDIN"


    static let IS_APP_SETTINGS_DOWNLOADED : String = "IS_APP_SETTINGS_DOWNLOADED"
    static let APP_SETTINGS_DOWNLOADED : String = "APP_SETTINGS_DOWNLOADED"
    static let APP_NAME : String = "APP_NAME"

    class func iterateKeychainItems(log: Bool, delete: Bool) {
        let secItemClasses = [
            kSecClassGenericPassword,
            kSecClassInternetPassword,
            kSecClassCertificate,
            kSecClassKey,
            kSecClassIdentity
        ]

        if (log) {
            for secItemClass in secItemClasses {
                let query: [String: Any] = [
                    kSecReturnAttributes as String: kCFBooleanTrue,
                    kSecMatchLimit as String: kSecMatchLimitAll,
                    kSecClass as String: secItemClass
                ]

                var result: AnyObject?
                let status = SecItemCopyMatching(query as CFDictionary, &result)
                if status == noErr {
                    print(result as Any)
                }
            }
            print("AppUsageMetadata.iterateKeychainItems ended.")
        }

        if (delete) {
            for secItemClass in secItemClasses {
                let dictionary = [kSecClass as String:secItemClass]
                SecItemDelete(dictionary as CFDictionary)
            }
        }
    }

        class func save(key: String, data: Data) -> OSStatus {
            let query = [
                kSecClass as String       : kSecClassGenericPassword as String,
                kSecAttrAccount as String : key,
                kSecValueData as String   : data ] as [String : Any]

            SecItemDelete(query as CFDictionary)

            return SecItemAdd(query as CFDictionary, nil)
        }

        class func load(key: String) -> Data? {
            let query = [
                kSecClass as String       : kSecClassGenericPassword,
                kSecAttrAccount as String : key,
                kSecReturnData as String  : kCFBooleanTrue,
                kSecMatchLimit as String  : kSecMatchLimitOne ] as [String : Any]

            var dataTypeRef: AnyObject? = nil

            let status: OSStatus = SecItemCopyMatching(query as CFDictionary, &dataTypeRef)

            if status == noErr {
                return dataTypeRef as! Data?
            } else {
                return nil
            }
        }

        class func createUniqueID() -> String {
            let uuid: CFUUID = CFUUIDCreate(nil)
            let cfStr: CFString = CFUUIDCreateString(nil, uuid)

            let swiftString: String = cfStr as String
            return swiftString
        }
    }

    extension Data {

        init<T>(from value: T) {
            var value = value
            self.init(buffer: UnsafeBufferPointer(start: &value, count: 1))
        }

        func to<T>(type: T.Type) -> T {
            return self.withUnsafeBytes { $0.pointee }
        }




}
```

> so now tell me how can I remove one key/item. for example, I want to
>   remove IS_USER_LOGGEDIN key. How it needs to be done?? please help me

Comment: can you add this piece of code in you delete method,atleast we get a track of whether the key is deleted or not
if (status != errSecSuccess) {
                    if let err = SecCopyErrorMessageString(status, nil) {
                        print("Remove failed: \(err)")
                    }
                }

Answer (score 1):

```
class func delete(key: String) {
    let query = [
        kSecClass as String             : kSecClassGenericPassword as String,
        kSecAttrAccount as String       : key] as [String : Any]

    SecItemDelete(query as CFDictionary)
}
```

Its similar to your save function. I'm just not setting the data and kSecClass class is same as your save function but if your key which needs to be delete has different class you can change that as well

Answer (score 0):

Theres a nice wrapper for accessing the system keychain on GitHub:

[SAMKeyChain](https://github.com/soffes/SAMKeychain)

Just use the "setPassword" and "deletePassword" functions for your needs.

Answer (score -2):

You can use **UserDefaults** as like Shared preferences
For **Swift 3:**
For set string value by using key
*UserDefaults.standard.set("2", forKey: "LOGINID")*

For get string value by using key
*let LoginID = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "LOGINID")!*

For remove by key
*UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "LOGINID")*

**For Swift2.2**
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
*defaults.setObject("2", forKey: "LOGINID")*

Comment: I know about user defaults. So the question is about Keychain